# Addressbook authorizated

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

in my app import contacts, but for authorize the user use:

log is empty. what is the error? 
solution?

```
var error:Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
let addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?
let status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()

if status == ABAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook) {
        (success, error) in
        if success {
            //code
            NSLog("OK")
        }
        else {
            NSLog("NO")
        } 
    }
    if status == ABAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        NSLog("OK")
    }
    else {
        NSLog("NO")
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the status is anything besides `.NotDetermined` ? In general, you really should use a [switch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) for enums, so the compiler can help you make sure you handle every case.

Comment: No nothing happens in any situation

Comment: You're second if statement should be outside of the first braces no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752627/accessing-ios-address-book-with-swift-array-count-of-zero